# UICollectionView is running before the data load from Web Api

Tags: swift

`UICollectionView` is running before data(`finalAllItems`) is populated from web api. I should show `UICollectionView` with data. I have added below line end of the `convertReturnsInToWantedType` function. But it did not fix the problem.             `outletForTheCollectionView.reloadData()` How can I show data in `UICollectionView`?

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var outletForTheCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var outletForThePageController: UIPageControl!

    var howmanyWords : Int = 0
    var dataList : [[String:Any]]?
    var finalAllItems = [AllItems]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadVerbs()

        outletForTheCollectionView.delegate = self
        outletForTheCollectionView.dataSource = self

        let xib = UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil)
        self.outletForTheCollectionView.register(xib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ViewCellID")

    }


    func loadVerbs ()
    {
        let urlString = "http://somelink/english/vocabularyVerbs.ashx"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)

        let request = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 30.0)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
        {
            (data, response, error) in
            if let result = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [[String:Any]]
            {
            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                   self.dataList = result
                   self.convertReturnsInToWantedType()
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    func convertReturnsInToWantedType()
    {

    // I populate finalAllItems array of dictionary object in here.
    // Code might be not well-written in this scope

    var datalistCount = dataList!.count
    howmanyWords = datalistCount
    datalistCount = datalistCount - 1
    let nullLabel : String = "variable is coming null from web api"

    for n in 0...datalistCount {

        let oneItem = self.dataList![n]

        var itemWord  : String = ""
        if let itemWordTemp = oneItem["itemWord"] as? String
        {
            itemWord = itemWordTemp
        }
        else
        {
            itemWord = nullLabel
        }

        var itemMeaning  : String = ""
        if let itemMeaningTemp = oneItem["itemMeaning"] as? String
        {
            itemMeaning = itemMeaningTemp
        }
        else
        {
            itemMeaning = nullLabel
        }

        var itemVerb2Form  : String = ""
        if let itemVerb2FormTemp = oneItem["itemVerb2Form"] as? String
        {
            itemVerb2Form = itemVerb2FormTemp
        }
        else
        {
            itemVerb2Form = nullLabel
        }

        var itemVerb3Form  : String = ""
        if let itemVerb3FormTemp = oneItem["itemVerb3Form"] as? String
        {
            itemVerb3Form = itemVerb3FormTemp
        }
        else
        {
            itemVerb3Form = nullLabel
        }

        var itemDefination  : String = ""
        if let itemDefinationTemp = oneItem["itemDefination"] as? String
        {
            itemDefination = itemDefinationTemp
        }
        else
        {
            itemDefination = nullLabel
        }

        var itemUsingInSentence  : String = ""
        if let itemUsingInSentenceTemp = oneItem["itemUsingInSentence"] as? String
        {
            itemUsingInSentence = itemUsingInSentenceTemp
        }
        else
        {
            itemUsingInSentence = nullLabel
        }

        var itemThisWordIsRelatedWithThatWord  : String = ""
        if let itemThisWordIsRelatedWithThatWordTemp = oneItem["itemThisWordIsRelatedWithThatWord"] as? String
        {
            itemThisWordIsRelatedWithThatWord = itemThisWordIsRelatedWithThatWordTemp
        }
        else
        {
            itemThisWordIsRelatedWithThatWord = nullLabel
        }

        var itemTrapReply1  : String = ""
        if let itemTrapReply1Temp = oneItem["itemTrapReply1"] as? String
        {
            itemTrapReply1 = itemTrapReply1Temp
        }
        else
        {
            itemTrapReply1 = nullLabel
        }

        var itemTrapReply2  : String = ""
        if let itemTrapReply2Temp = oneItem["itemTrapReply2"] as? String
        {
            itemTrapReply2 = itemTrapReply2Temp
        }
        else
        {
            itemTrapReply2 = nullLabel
        }

        var itemTrapReply3  : String = ""
        if let itemTrapReply3Temp = oneItem["itemTrapReply3"] as? String
        {
            itemTrapReply3 = itemTrapReply3Temp
        }
        else
        {
            itemTrapReply3 = nullLabel
        }

        var itemTrapReply4  : String = ""
        if let itemTrapReply4Temp = oneItem["itemTrapReply4"] as? String
        {
            itemTrapReply4 = itemTrapReply4Temp
        }
        else
        {
            itemTrapReply4 = nullLabel
        }

        finalAllItems.append(
            AllItems(
                itemWord:itemWord,
                itemWordMeaning: itemMeaning,
                itemVerb2Form: itemVerb2Form,
                itemVerb3Form: itemVerb3Form,
                itemDefination: itemDefination,
                itemUsingInSentence: itemUsingInSentence,
                itemThisWordIsReleatedWithThatWord: itemThisWordIsRelatedWithThatWord,
                itemTrapReply1: itemTrapReply1,
                itemTrapReply2: itemTrapReply2,
                itemTrapReply3: itemTrapReply3,
                itemTrapReply4: itemTrapReply4
            )
        )

    } // FOR LOOP ENDS     
} // convertReturnsInToWantedType ENDS

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}

extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,  UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //return self.dataList.count
        return self.howmanyWords
    }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    let cell = outletForTheCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ViewCellID", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.outletForTheViewInCell.backgroundColor = .lightGray


    // word label
    cell.outletForTheLabelInCell.text = self.finalAllItems[indexPath.row].itemWord



    print(finalAllItems[indexPath.row].itemWord)
    var allRepliesArray =
        [
            self.finalAllItems[indexPath.row].itemTrapReply1,
            self.finalAllItems[indexPath.row].itemTrapReply2,
            self.finalAllItems[indexPath.row].itemTrapReply3,
            self.finalAllItems[indexPath.row].itemTrapReply4,
            self.finalAllItems[indexPath.row].itemWordMeaning
    ]

    print(allRepliesArray)
    print(allRepliesArray.count)
    let randomIndex1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(allRepliesArray.count)))
    cell.btnOptionA.setTitle(allRepliesArray[randomIndex1], for: .normal)
    allRepliesArray = allRepliesArray.filter {$0 != allRepliesArray[randomIndex1]}
    print(allRepliesArray.count)

    let randomIndex2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(allRepliesArray.count)))
    cell.btnOptionB.setTitle(allRepliesArray[randomIndex2], for: .normal)
    allRepliesArray = allRepliesArray.filter {$0 != allRepliesArray[randomIndex2]}

    let randomIndex3 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(allRepliesArray.count)))
    cell.btnOptionC.setTitle(allRepliesArray[randomIndex3], for: .normal)
    allRepliesArray = allRepliesArray.filter {$0 != allRepliesArray[randomIndex3]}

    let randomIndex4 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(allRepliesArray.count)))
    cell.btnOptionD.setTitle(allRepliesArray[randomIndex4], for: .normal)
    allRepliesArray = allRepliesArray.filter {$0 != allRepliesArray[randomIndex4]}

    cell.btnOptionE.setTitle(allRepliesArray[0], for: .normal)

    cell.correctReply = self.correctAnswerArray[indexPath.row]
    print("cevapDogruMu: \(cevapDogruMu)")

    cell.dismiss = { [weak self] str  in
        //Here.
        if str == "true"
        {
            cell.outletForTheViewInCell.backgroundColor = .green
        }
        else
        {
            cell.outletForTheViewInCell.backgroundColor = .red
        }
    }

    return cell
}




    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        return screenSize
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let index = self.outletForTheCollectionView.contentOffset.x / self.outletForTheCollectionView.frame.size.width
        self.outletForThePageController.currentPage = Int(index)
        //self.outletForThePageController.numberOfPages = dataList.count
        self.outletForThePageController.numberOfPages = self.howmanyWords
    }

    class SnappingCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

        override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
            guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset, withScrollingVelocity: velocity) }

            var offsetAdjustment = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
            let horizontalOffset = proposedContentOffset.x + collectionView.contentInset.left

            let targetRect = CGRect(x: proposedContentOffset.x, y: 0, width: collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: collectionView.bounds.size.height)

            let layoutAttributesArray = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: targetRect)

            layoutAttributesArray?.forEach({ (layoutAttributes) in
                let itemOffset = layoutAttributes.frame.origin.x
                if fabsf(Float(itemOffset - horizontalOffset)) < fabsf(Float(offsetAdjustment)) {
                    offsetAdjustment = itemOffset - horizontalOffset
                }
            })

            return CGPoint(x: proposedContentOffset.x + offsetAdjustment, y: proposedContentOffset.y)
        }
    }
} // extension ENDS

extension MutableCollection {
    /// Shuffles the contents of this collection.
    mutating func shuffle() {
        let c = count
        guard c > 1 else { return }

        for (firstUnshuffled, unshuffledCount) in zip(indices, stride(from: c, to: 1, by: -1)) {
            // Change `Int` in the next line to `IndexDistance` in < Swift 4.1
            let d: Int = numericCast(arc4random_uniform(numericCast(unshuffledCount)))
            let i = index(firstUnshuffled, offsetBy: d)
            swapAt(firstUnshuffled, i)
        }
    }
}

extension Sequence {
    /// Returns an array with the contents of this sequence, shuffled.
    func shuffled() -> [Element] {
        var result = Array(self)
        result.shuffle()
        return result
    }
}
```

This is an example for the JSON return

```
[
  {
    "itemWord": "surpass",
    "itemMeaning": "lorem",
    "itemVerb2Form": "surpassVerb2",
    "itemVerb3Form": "surpassVerb3",
    "itemDefination": null,
    "itemUsingInSentence": null,
    "itemThisWordIsRelatedWithThatWord": null,
    "itemTrapReply1": "lorem",
    "itemTrapReply2": "lorem",
    "itemTrapReply3": "lorem",
    "itemTrapReply4": "lorem"
  },
  {
    "itemWord": "affect",
    "itemMeaning": "lorem",
    "itemVerb2Form": "affectVerb2",
    "itemVerb3Form": "affectVerb3",
    "itemDefination": null,
    "itemUsingInSentence": null,
    "itemThisWordIsRelatedWithThatWord": null,
    "itemTrapReply1": "lorem",
    "itemTrapReply2": "lorem",
    "itemTrapReply3": "lorem",
    "itemTrapReply4": "lorem"
  }
]
```

AllItems.swift file

```
import Foundation

class AllItems
{
    var itemWord : String = "" // 1
    var itemWordMeaning : String = "" // 2
    var itemVerb2Form : String = "" // 3
    var itemVerb3Form : String = "" // 4
    var itemDefination : String = "Verb" // 5
    var itemUsingInSentence: String = "" // 6
    var itemThisWordIsReleatedWithThatWord : String  = "" // 7

    var itemTrapReply1 : String = ""
    var itemTrapReply2 : String = ""
    var itemTrapReply3 : String = ""
    var itemTrapReply4 : String = ""

    init(
        itemWord:String,
        itemWordMeaning:String,
        itemVerb2Form:String,
        itemVerb3Form:String,
        itemDefination: String,
        itemUsingInSentence:String,
        itemThisWordIsReleatedWithThatWord: String,
        itemTrapReply1: String,
        itemTrapReply2: String,
        itemTrapReply3: String,
        itemTrapReply4: String)
    {
        self.itemWord = itemWord //1
        self.itemWordMeaning = itemWordMeaning //2
        self.itemVerb2Form = itemVerb2Form // 3
        self.itemVerb3Form = itemVerb3Form // 4
        self.itemDefination = itemDefination // 5
        self.itemUsingInSentence = itemUsingInSentence // 6
        self.itemThisWordIsReleatedWithThatWord = itemThisWordIsReleatedWithThatWord // 7

        self.itemTrapReply1 = itemTrapReply1 // 8
        self.itemTrapReply2 = itemTrapReply2 // 9
        self.itemTrapReply3 = itemTrapReply3 // 10
        self.itemTrapReply4 = itemTrapReply4 // 11
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the current outcome of this code?

Comment: I would like to show data(from web api method) in UI Collection View. I have created this test application to learn solution for this problem. Dear @AbdulRehmanWarraich

Comment: ok share `AllItems` model.

Comment: also JSON you are trying to map.

Comment: I have added. AllItems.swift, JSON return and the cellForItemAt method. @AbdulRehmanWarraich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data request from API is asynchronous. To solve your problem you can call the `reloadData` function when your `finalAllItems` variable is setted.

```
var finalAllItems = [AllItems]() {
    didSet {
       outletForTheCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you're not setting up the values in your cells.
Right now you're just seeing a bunch of gray cells, right? Maybe just one?

In the `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`, you should set up the values to be shown in the cells before returning them. All you're doing right now is setting up the background color, nothing else.

You should do something like `cell.setUpData(finalAllItems[indexPath.row])` inside that function, and then in the cell class you have to create the setUpData method and do whatever you want to do with your data in the cell.

And yes, you should call `outletForTheCollectionView.reloadData()` every time you want to show new data.

Comment: I see blank white page like all object isHidden=true By the way, I have checked it, HomeViewController is an initial view controller. And Home View Controller Scene is related with HomeViewController.swift file. Dear @Roberto

Comment: Where are you initializing the `finalAllItems` array? It seems to be empty all the time.